# Python decorator from chained calls

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to create a decorator from a chain of calls. It does not seem to be supported by syntax.

```
from functools import wraps


class Bar:
    def wrapper(self):
        def _outer(fun):
            @wraps(fun)
            def _f(*a, **kw):
                print('I am in decorator')
                return fun(*a, **kw)
            return _f
        return _outer


def foo():
    return Bar()


# @foo().wrapper()  # Invalid syntax
# def f():
#     pass


# @(foo().wrapper())  # Invalid syntax
# def f():
#     pass


def f():
    pass


f = foo().wrapper()(f)
f()
```

Am I missing something? For some reasons, such a thing would be extremely useful in my project.

Thanks

Comment: yup, that syntax is not supported, it is made very limited by design.

Comment: you can always do `f = foo().wrapper(f)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indeed, the potential of expressiveness in completely gone... Such a pity.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
wrapper = foo().wrapper()

@wrapper
def foo():
  pass
```

Comment: Note that according to the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-decorator), it is only the parentheses after `foo` that are a problem. `@foo.wrapper()` would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have to invoke a chain of things.

Comment: Using [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) might solve your problem. They add a function call as an attribute lookup.